# How to link a linux system to an existing RAID1 on 2 external hard drives?

Tags: linux, raid-1, mdadm

I installed Debian Linux (Wheezy) on a small HDD, added two identical large (2TB) HDDs, and built a RAID1 (without using `lvm`), using `mdadm`. I have stored a large quantity of files on the RAID.

I run the RAID from a third HDD so as to make it simple to update or replace the Linux system, without disturbing the RAID.

The small HDD has just died! I have replaced it, reinstalled Debian Wheezy (with the large drives unplugged), and all is well. How do I now reattach the RAID system, without disturbing the saved files?

**UPDATE:** Following Jake's helpful advice, I investigated without the SATA (RAID) drives plugged in:

```
lsblk gives:  
sda = sda1, sda2 (“/”), sda3 (swap), sda4  
sr0 rom  
sr1 rom
```

Then I rebooted with the two SATA drives attached. They should have two different RAID1 arrays, one of 20GB and one of 1960GB, I think formatted ext3.

`lsblk` now gives:

```
sr0  
sda = sda1, sda2 (/), sda3 (SWAP), sda4  
sdc = sdc1, sdc2 (md124,raid1), sdc3 (md125,raid1), sdc4  
sdb = sdb1, sdb2 (md126,raid1), sdb3 (md127,raid1), sdb4
```

Some messages flashed on the screen during bootup, so I consulted dmesg:

```
md: md127 stopped  
md: bind`<sdb3>`   
md: raid1 personality registered for level 1  
md/raid1:md127: active with 1 out of 2 mirrors   
md127: detected capacity change from 0 to 1.96GB   
md127: unknown partition table
```

... and exactly similar entries for `md126`, `md125`, `md124`.

So Linux has auto-detected and mounted the RAID arrays, but assumes they are four separate arrays?  And can’t read the partition tables?
How can I correct this?

Comment: You'd better not to cross-post your questions

Answer (score 1):

You say this:

> I run the RAID from a third HDD so as to make it simple to update or
>   replace the Linux system, without disturbing the RAID.

Then say this.

> The small HDD has just died! I have replaced it, reinstalled Debian
>   Wheezy (with the large drives unplugged), and all is well. How do I
>   now reattach the RAID system, without disturbing the saved files?

A bit vague on your RAID setup, without knowing the system specifics, I will explain how you can manually mount/unmount a volume in Linux. But please note: **Without knowing the specifics of your local setup, this should be considered a generic guide on how to handle this task and non a true step-by-step guide to a solution.**

First, you should just be able to plugin the RAIDed disks and mount them like any other volume. What I would recommend is running [`lsblk`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman8/lsblk.8.html) before you do anything else:

```
lsblk
```

The output would be something like this; this is from my own `sandbox` Ubuntu install in VirtualBox:

```
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                             8:0    0     8G  0 disk 
├─sda1                          8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                          8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                          8:5    0   7.8G  0 part 
  ├─sandbox--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0   6.7G  0 lvm  /
  └─sandbox--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0  1020M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

The `sda` and related partitions are the boot volume on my `sandbox` install. When you plug in the RAID, a volume called `sdb` should show up in that list. If you rerun `lsblk` after hooking that up you should see it listed.

Now as to how to mount it, you would need to create a directory to be a mount point. For testing, I recommend doing this in your user directory. Something like this:

```
mkdir -p ~my_mount
```

Of course that directory would be empty. But now if you run the following `mount` command via `sudo` you should be able to mount that RAID without issue:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 ~/my_mount
```

Note how I am mounting `/dev/sdb1` instead of `/dev/sdb`; that is because the drives should be properly partitioned with `sdb1` being the first usable partition. Now if you run a simple `ls -la` on that `~/my_mount` like this:

```
ls -la ~/my_mount
```

You will be able to read the contents of that volume. And if you want to unmount the volume, you can just run this `umount` command:

```
sudo umount ~/my_mount
```

And that’s that! You can always change the location of the mount point from `~/my_mount` to something else. But like I said at the outset, this is a basic explanation on how to manually mount and unmount a volume on a Linux system. There might be specifics about your RAID setup that are not entirely clear from your post so use this as a guide to explain how to generically mount/unmount and not a canonical list of steps that will assuredly solve your issue.

**EDIT:** And [here is a site with details](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/05/08/how-to-mount-software-raid1-member-using-mdadm/) on how to mount a RAID member with `mdadm`.

Comment: Jake, very many thanks for your thoughtful help.  And the link was also great.

Comment: Without the SATA (RAID) drives plugged in, <lsblk> gives me

sda = sda1, sda2 (“/”), sda3 (swap), sda4
sr0  rom
sr1 rom

(for some reason this machine has TWO CD-rom drives - remember the days of copying CDs directly?)

I rebooted with the two SATA drives attached.  They have two different RAID1 arrays, one of 20GB and one of 1960GB.  <lsblk> now gives

sda=sda1,sda2(md126,raid1),sda3(md127,raid1),sda4
sdb=sdb1,sdb2(md124,raid1),sdb3(md125,raid1),sdb4
sdc=sdc1,2(/),3(SWAP),4
sr0
sr1

Comment: and <dmesg> shows
md: md127 stopped
md: bind<sda3>
md: raid1 personality registered for level 1
md/raid1:md127: active with 1 out of 2 mirrors
md127? detected capacity change from 0 to 1.96GB
md127 unknown partition table
and exactly similar entries for md126,md125,md124.

So linux has auto-detected and mounted the RAID arrays, but assumed they are four separate arrays?

Being hassled by 5-minute limit on comment editing, sorry about the multiple entries